# Rails 5.2: How to create fields_for each I18n key value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, ruby-on-rails-5.2

In my `_form.html.erb` I have nested fields, where for an Offer I would like to save multiple Discount types with values:

```
<%= f.fields_for @offer.discounts do |discount| %>
  <% I18n.t(:discount_type).each do |type| %>
     <div class="form-group row discount-list">
       <label class="col-sm-8 control-label">
          <%= discount.label I18n.t("discount_type.#{type[0]}") %><br/>
       </label>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
         <%= discount.hidden_field :discount_type, value: type[0] %>
         <%= discount.number_field :value, 
             value: (@offer.new_record? ? '0.00' : discount.value), 
             class: "form-control allow_numeric" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

At the moment my form is populated correctly as I would like it to be, however values are not saving since:

1. in my params I see only 1 of 3 discount types like this:
   `"seller_discount"=>{"discount_type"=>"special", "value"=>"5"}`
2. there is error `Unpermitted parameter: :seller_discount`
3. records are not saving

My `Seller::Offer` model looks like this:

```
has_many :offer_discounts, class_name: "Seller::OfferDiscount"
has_many :discounts, class_name: "Seller::Discount", through: :offer_discounts, inverse_of: :offers
accepts_nested_attributes_for :discounts, allow_destroy: true
```

My controller is simple as:

```
  def new
    @offer = Seller::Offer.new
  end

  private

  def offer_params
    params.require(:seller_offer).permit(
      :company_id, :name, :base_price,
      discounts_attributes: [:id, :discount_type, :value, :_destroy]
    )
  end
```

So far I've been trying different ideas from [Rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for), however no luck. Probably in my specific case, twist is where I try to iterate over `I18n.t(:discount_type)` an create input field for each discount type (buy key).

I'll be happy for any hint how to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: what are `type[0]` and `type[1]` doing here?

Comment: @lacostenycoder My bad - in both places it has to be `type[0]`, which is key for `I18n.t(:discount_type)`

Comment: what type of object is `type` if you have to pass an index? and why should it be zero on each iteration?

Comment: @lacostenycoder It's hash where keys are my `discount_type` and values are translated names. I believe it shouldn't be zero on each iteration. I've tried `@offer.discounts.build`, however then I get my form multiplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to have my form working for both New and Edit actions, final solution is this:

```
        <% if params[:action] == 'new' %>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <!-- Discounts for new form !-->
          <% I18n.t(:discount_type).each do |type| %>
          <%= f.fields_for :discounts, @offer.discounts.build do |disc| %>
              <div class="form-group row discount-list">
                <label class="col-sm-8 control-label">
                  <%= disc.label I18n.t("discount_type.#{type[0]}") %><br/>
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <%= disc.hidden_field :discount_type, value: type[0] %>
                  <%= disc.number_field :value, value: '0.00',
                      class: "form-control allow_numeric" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <% elsif params[:action] == 'edit' %>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <!-- Discounts for edit form !-->
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :discounts do |d| %>
          <div class="form-group row discount-list">
            <%= d.input :discount_type, as: :hidden %>
            <label class="col-sm-8 control-label">
              <%= d.label I18n.t("discount_type.#{d.object.discount_type}") %><br/>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <%= d.input :value, label: false, input_html: { id: d.object.discount_type+"_discount",
                  class: "form-control allow_numeric" } %>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

Edit action is done with [simple_form_fields_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models)

Obviously not shiny solution, but looks like this works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're iterating over `discount_type` I think that needs to be an array type in your `offer_params` method.

```
def offer_params
  params.require(:seller_offer).permit(
    :company_id, :name, :base_price,
    seller_discounts_attributes: [:id, :discount_types => [:discount_type, :value], :_destroy]
  )
end
```

But what happens if you try to use `fields_for` helper?

```
<%= f.fields_for @offer.discounts do |discount| %>
  <%= f.fields_for I18n.t(:discount_type) do |type| %>
     <div class="form-group row discount-list">
       <label class="col-sm-8 control-label">
          <%= discount.label I18n.t("discount_type.#{type[0]}") %><br/>
       </label>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
         <%= discount.hidden_field :discount_type, value: type[0] %>
         <%= discount.number_field :value, 
             value: (@offer.new_record? ? '0.00' : discount.value), 
             class: "form-control allow_numeric" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In my `seller_discounts` table I have two columns: `discount_type` and `value` where I would like to store values. Basically I would like to store a record for each `I18n.t(:discount_type)` key and that key goes as value for `discount_type` column.

Comment: I believe you wanted it to be `{:discount_types => [:discount_type, :value]}`, however  that doesn't work as I get `Unpermitted parameter: :seller_discount` and only one value is passed: `"seller_discount"=>{"discount_type"=>"special", "value"=>"3"}`